# Why Prestashop doesn't redirect?

Tags: php, redirect, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a module that call the Tools::redirect($myurl) function.
If I debug in that function (file /classes/Tools.php) :

```
public static function redirect($url, $base_uri = __PS_BASE_URI__, Link $link = null, $headers = null)
{
    if (!$link)
        $link = Context::getContext()->link;

    if (strpos($url, 'http://') === false && strpos($url, 'https://') === false && $link)
    {
        if (strpos($url, $base_uri) === 0)
            $url = substr($url, strlen($base_uri));
        if (strpos($url, 'index.php?controller=') !== false && strpos($url, 'index.php/') == 0)
        {
            $url = substr($url, strlen('index.php?controller='));
            if (Configuration::get('PS_REWRITING_SETTINGS'))
                $url = Tools::strReplaceFirst('&', '?', $url);
        }

        $explode = explode('?', $url);
        // don't use ssl if url is home page
        // used when logout for example
        $use_ssl = !empty($url);
        $url = $link->getPageLink($explode[0], $use_ssl);
        if (isset($explode[1]))
            $url .= '?'.$explode[1];
    }

    // Send additional headers
    if ($headers)
    {
        if (!is_array($headers))
            $headers = array($headers);

        foreach ($headers as $header)
            header($header);
    }
    header('Location: '.$url);
    exit;
}
```

setting a die('test'); the line before the header("location"), I have my debug. If I put my test between header() and exit; I still have my test.
So far, everything seems normal. Nevertheless, my URL in the variable is http://www.example.com/connexion?back=http://www.example.com/1-my-category and my browser displays a 403 forbidden page. If I cut/paste the URL in the variable, it will display the login form. So, why the header location is not redirecting me to the page ? I'm getting lost...

Comment: have you verified if you are redirecting to a secured page, and that you are logged in and have access permission?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The 403 redirection was in the CategoryController in case of user not logged. So I override the controller redirecting to my login page if user is not logged.